# One of two disk members of RAID-5 became invisible after an abrupt shutdown?

Tags: ubuntu, data-recovery, raid5

I have two disks (sda and sdc, I don't know the fate of the others if any) assembled as RAID-5. After several abrupt shutdowns, one of the raid members became invisible and I couldn't re-assemble it. I am not very familiar with Linux file systems including RAID-5. As far as I know, I won't lose any files thanks to RAID-5 but I don't know whether my sdc disk is broken or not, if not is it possible to re-assemble them without any information loss, or if it is broken how can I access my files. I appreciate any help!

```
$ lsblk -o NAME,SIZE,FSTYPE,TYPE,MOUNTPOINT

NAME     SIZE FSTYPE                        TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0   27,1M squashfs                      loop /snap/snapd/7264
loop1     55M squashfs                      loop /snap/core18/1705
loop2  240,8M squashfs                      loop /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/24
loop3   62,1M squashfs                      loop /snap/gtk-common-themes/1506
loop4   49,8M squashfs                      loop /snap/snap-store/433
sda      3,7T promise_fasttrack_raid_member disk 
└─sda1   3,7T linux_raid_member             part 
sdb    465,8G                               disk 
├─sdb1 186,4G ext4                          part /
├─sdb2     1K                               part 
├─sdb3 268,2G ext4                          part /home
└─sdb5  11,2G swap                          part [SWAP]
```

and

```
$sudo parted -l

Model: ATA WDC WD40EZRX-00S (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 4001GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name  Flags
 1      1049kB  4001GB  4001GB  ext4               raid


Model: ATA Samsung SSD 840 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 500GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End    Size    Type      File system     Flags
 1      1049kB  200GB  200GB   primary   ext4            boot
 2      200GB   212GB  12,0GB  extended
 5      200GB   212GB  12,0GB  logical   linux-swap(v1)
 3      212GB   500GB  288GB   primary   ext4
```

I can only see it in "Disks" application in Ubuntu and it says "no media" for sdc disk.

[image]

The sda partition seems to be correct.

[image]

I couldn't re-assemble it with

```
sudo mdadm --assemble --scan
```

I got the following errors when upgrading ubuntu 20.

```
grub-probe: warning: disk does not exist, so falling back to partition device /dev/sdc1.
grub-probe: error: cannot read `/dev/sdc1': Input/output error.
```

**Update:**

It showed the disk after reboot (I don't know why or how). But still can't assemble and mount.

```
$ lsblk -o NAME,SIZE,FSTYPE,TYPE,MOUNTPOINT
NAME     SIZE FSTYPE                        TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0     55M squashfs                      loop /snap/core18/1705
loop1   61,9M squashfs                      loop /snap/core20/1270
loop2   62,1M squashfs                      loop /snap/gtk-common-themes/1506
loop3  108,1M squashfs                      loop /snap/remmina/5130
loop4   49,8M squashfs                      loop /snap/snap-store/433
loop5  240,8M squashfs                      loop /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/24
loop6   27,1M squashfs                      loop /snap/snapd/7264
loop7  247,9M squashfs                      loop /snap/gnome-3-38-2004/87
loop8   55,5M squashfs                      loop /snap/core18/2284
loop9   43,4M squashfs                      loop /snap/snapd/14549
loop10     4K squashfs                      loop /snap/bare/5
loop11  65,2M squashfs                      loop /snap/gtk-common-themes/1519
loop12  54,2M squashfs                      loop /snap/snap-store/558
loop13   219M squashfs                      loop /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/77
sda      3,7T promise_fasttrack_raid_member disk 
└─sda1   3,7T linux_raid_member             part 
sdb    465,8G                               disk 
├─sdb1 186,4G ext4                          part /
├─sdb2     1K                               part 
├─sdb3 268,2G ext4                          part /home
└─sdb5  11,2G swap                          part [SWAP]
sdc      3,7T promise_fasttrack_raid_member disk 
└─sdc1   3,7T linux_raid_member             part
```

I tried to mdadm assemble and then mount it, but failed.

```
$ sudo mdadm --assemble --scan --force
$ sudo mount /dev/md0 /home/bilgen/
mount: /home/person: can't read superblock on /dev/md0.


$ cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid1] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10] 
md0 : inactive sdc1[2] sda1[1]
      7813771264 blocks super 1.2
       
unused devices: <none>


$ sudo mdadm --examine --scan
ARRAY /dev/md/0  metadata=1.2 UUID=92fd33d9:351dcee8:c809916a:b46055e5 name=zencefil:0
```

Verified the RAID disks sda1 and sdc1. The state of sda1 is clean but of sdc1 is active. I think this is important to debug the problem.
I verified it is RAID-5 but one of the disks should have been broken already because I only observed two disks when I got the computer. Now I realized it.

```
$ sudo mdadm -E /dev/sda1
/dev/sda1:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x0
     Array UUID : 92fd33d9:351dcee8:c809916a:b46055e5
           Name : zencefil:0
  Creation Time : Thu Mar 12 00:17:27 2015
     Raid Level : **raid5**
   Raid Devices : **3**

 Avail Dev Size : 7813771264 (3725.90 GiB 4000.65 GB)
     Array Size : 7813770240 (7451.79 GiB 8001.30 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 7813770240 (3725.90 GiB 4000.65 GB)
    Data Offset : 262144 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
   Unused Space : before=262064 sectors, after=1024 sectors
          **State : clean**
    Device UUID : 6212bf12:f2bacb20:6a10a588:ac50cb2d

    Update Time : Mon Jan 24 20:04:23 2022
       Checksum : cfb60638 - correct
         Events : 6360009

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 512K

   Device Role : Active device 1
   Array State : .AA ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)

$ sudo mdadm -E /dev/sdc1
/dev/sdc1:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x0
     Array UUID : 92fd33d9:351dcee8:c809916a:b46055e5
           Name : zencefil:0
  Creation Time : Thu Mar 12 00:17:27 2015
     Raid Level : **raid5**
   Raid Devices : **3**

 Avail Dev Size : 7813771264 (3725.90 GiB 4000.65 GB)
     Array Size : 7813770240 (7451.79 GiB 8001.30 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 7813770240 (3725.90 GiB 4000.65 GB)
    Data Offset : 262144 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
   Unused Space : before=262064 sectors, after=1024 sectors
          **State : active**
    Device UUID : daef079b:176d487a:cb152bdb:3d2548f9

    Update Time : Mon Jan 24 20:04:23 2022
       Checksum : cf7e70ca - correct
         Events : 6360009

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 512K

   Device Role : Active device 2
   Array State : .AA ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)
```

Messages can help to undestand the situation

```
dmesg | grep md0
[    8.147671] md/raid:md0: not clean -- starting background reconstruction
[    8.147750] md/raid:md0: device sdc1 operational as raid disk 2
[    8.147755] md/raid:md0: device sda1 operational as raid disk 1
[    8.149553] md/raid:md0: cannot start dirty degraded array.
[    8.149943] md/raid:md0: failed to run raid set.
[ 2878.821074] EXT4-fs (md0): unable to read superblock
```

The things getting more interesting

```
mdadm -D /dev/md0
/dev/md0:
           Version : 1.2
     Creation Time : Thu Mar 12 00:17:27 2015
        Raid Level : raid5
     Used Dev Size : 18446744073709551615
      Raid Devices : 3
     Total Devices : 2
       Persistence : Superblock is persistent

       Update Time : Mon Jan 24 20:04:23 2022
             State : active, FAILED, Not Started 
    Active Devices : 2
   Working Devices : 2
    Failed Devices : 0
     Spare Devices : 0

            Layout : left-symmetric
        Chunk Size : 512K

Consistency Policy : unknown

              Name : zencefil:0
              UUID : 92fd33d9:351dcee8:c809916a:b46055e5
            Events : 6360009

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       -       0        0        0      removed
       -       0        0        1      removed
       -       0        0        2      removed

       -       8        1        1      sync   /dev/sda1
       -       8       33        2      sync   /dev/sdc1
```

Comment: "I have two disks (sda and sdc) assembled as RAID-5.": no, RAID-5 requires 3 disks in normal operations. If you had two disks in RAID-5, that meant it was already in a degraded state, and losing an additional disk would then be fatal to data. Maybe you are talking about RAID-1 which requires only 2 disks?

Comment: The person who set up it told me RAID-5. But you are right, when I got the computer, I observed 2 disk RAID members but either one of them was already broken, or it is RAID 1 as you said. How can I validate the RAID type?

Comment: Your command tells it appears to be RAID-5. So I'm puzzled about this missing disk. You got 2 so the 3rd's missing. If you just recovered sdc1 and that 3rd has always been missing, then you should have a serious talk with the person who set up this RAID-5.

Comment: And you should consider securing your data: they are not protected right now.

Comment: You are right @A.B, how can I access the data in this situation? I was able to mount it with these two disks and it is the only way I know to get the data.

Comment: I can read "cannot start dirty degraded array.". Probably because you got a fault on a degraded array, ie a 2nd fault on a setup intended to protect from only 1 fault. I don't have knowledge on how to recover from this *without risking losing data*. I'd do a verbatim backup of the two disks to two other disks (as file rather than as block to avoid confusing the MD detection) before proceeding any further.